# my event don't fire in the next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile. And to tell you the truth, my head is spinning right now.

I have this code:

```
            //this event happens in my index.php/page1
            //this works
            $(document).delegate('.front-page-down','swipedown', function (event) {
                $.mobile.changePage('#notification', { transition: "slidedown"});
            });

            $(document).delegate('.swipeup','swipeup', function (event) {
                $.mobile.changePage('#front-page', { transition: "slideup"});
            });
            //this event happens in my next page/page2
            //doesn't work, I have to manually refresh the page first
            $(document).delegate('.sns-down','swipedown', function (event) {
                $.mobile.changePage('#featured', { transition: "slidedown"});
            });

            $(document).delegate('.featured-up','swipeup', function (event) {
                $.mobile.changePage('#sns-page', { transition: "slideup"});
            });
```

The first 2 (class front-page-down & swipeup) works because it fires in my index.php or first load of my page but the 3rd code (class sns-down & featured-up) won't, I would have to manually refresh the page first for it to work. Now why is it reacting like that?

Please help anyone.

Comment: Are the functions passed to delegate called at all? Have you added `console.log`s or something to prove this? From the browser console, what does `$(".sns-down")` return after first, second, third, etc page load?

Comment: can't use console.log coz i'm testing it in my mobile browser. I can only use alert(). The first two trigger the alert(). But when I go to the next page and trigger the 3rd and 4th delegates, it won't fire. T_T

Comment: Can you test on desktop Chrome? If not, then it might be a good idea to make sure your app works on both mobile and desktop for testing purposes.

Comment: hmmm., can't really swipedown or swipeup event in a desktop. So I can only use alert. I know my function is working but why is it that I have to refresh the 2nd page first for the function to work.

Comment: Having the ability to use your app on desktop will help your testing in the long run. Alternatively, use something like jsconsole.com.

Comment: hi, trace the error to this: $.mobile.changePage('#featured', { transition: "slidedown"});. This function don't work in my next page. Tried to comment this part in added an alert function and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because each page is completely independent of each other. Events registered on `index.php` won't influence any other page. So you need to register them again on the second page.

Comment: added the 3rd and 4th event in my second page. Still it won't trigger.

Comment: Anything in the error console? There are really nodes with the class `sns-down` on the page?

Comment: hi, trace the error to this: $.mobile.changePage('#featured', { transition: "slidedown"});. This function don't work in my next page. Tried to comment this part in added an alert function and it worked. –